# ¿Cómo unir 2 funciones en JS?

Tags: javascript, datatables

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo este inconveniente ya que no se cómo integrar la función `createdRow` a mi código JS, me envía un error que el ID `tablaPersonas` ya esta siendo utilizado. Espero puedan ayudarme. ¿Cómo unir 2 funciones?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tablaPersonas').DataTable( {
    createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
        if ( data[1] > 1 ) {
            $('td', row).eq(0).addClass('highlight');

        }
    }
} );
} );
```

Y el resto:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   tablaPersonas = $("#tablaPersonas").DataTable({

       "columnDefs":[{
        "targets": -1,
        "data":null,
        "defaultContent": ""  
       }],

        //Para cambiar el lenguaje a español
    "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "Columnvisibility": "DES",
            "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sSearch": "REALIZAR BÚSQUEDA:",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast":"Último",
                "sNext":"Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
             },
             "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
       },


        //para usar los botones   
        responsive: "true",
        dom: 'Bfrtilp',       
        buttons:[ 
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                className: 'btn btn-success'
            },
            {
                extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger'

            },
            {
                extend:    'print',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
                className: 'btn btn-info'
            },

            { extend:'colvis', 
              text: 'Ocultar Columna'
        },


        ]       

    });


});
```

El error es el siguiente:

> DataTables warning: table id=tablaPersonas - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: Podrias mostrar el error completo que te tira?

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=tablaPersonas - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: Por favor, agrega el error completo en la pregunta, porque tu traduccion no es lo que dice el error ;)

Comment: El error es el siguiente:

DataTables warning: table id=tablaPersonas - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see datatables.net/tn

Comment: Cambiá el nombre de tu tabla: tablaPersonas a tablaPersonas2 y en el js  $("#tablaPersonas2").DataTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo estas usando dos veces el `$(document).ready()` en la misma pagina y en su interior inicializas el componente DataTable

Según la descripción del error que pones, lo que dice es que el Datatable para ese elemento HTML ya esta creado... esto se debe a que lo inicializas 2 veces.

Puedes unir todo en una sola función... recuerda que el `$(document).ready()` es el handler que escucha cuando la pagina esta lista (html rendereado, css/js descargados) y ejecuta una función .... por lo gral se usa una sola vez por pagina y en la función que le asignamos tiene la lógica para inicalizar lo que sea necesario.

Queda asi (revisa que no falte algún cierre de {}, pudo fallar el copy/paste):

````
   tablaPersonas = $("#tablaPersonas").DataTable({
       createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
          if ( data[1] > 1 ) {
             $('td', row).eq(0).addClass('highlight');

          }
       },

       "columnDefs":[{
        "targets": -1,
        "data":null,
        "defaultContent": ""  
       }],

       //Para cambiar el lenguaje a español
       "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "Columnvisibility": "DES",
            "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sSearch": "REALIZAR BÚSQUEDA:",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primero",
                "sLast":"Último",
                "sNext":"Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
             },
             "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
        },

        //para usar los botones   
        responsive: "true",
        dom: 'Bfrtilp',       
        buttons:[ 
            {
                extend:    'excelHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                className: 'btn btn-success'
            },
            {
                extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> ',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger'

            },
            {
                extend:    'print',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
                className: 'btn btn-info'
            },
            { extend:'colvis', 
              text: 'Ocultar Columna'},
        ]       
    });
});```
````

Comment: Muchas gracias Andres Lozada Mosto por el apoyo me sirvió de mucho.